# Several query params URL in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, query-string

Can't construct URL containing 3 params. 
Did not find any appropriate existing example in the web.

routers.py

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'reservation(?P<param1>)', ReservationViewSet, 'reservation')
```

This works with one param. 
What is the correct syntax to add two more params to resolve URL's like:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/general/reservation?enterprise=4&start=01-01-2015&end=01-31-2016

?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _"3 params"_? `api`, `general`, and `reservation` **or** `enterprise`, `start`, and `end`?

Comment: enterprise, start, and end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short I suggest you pick one or the other way and not mix GET parameters with the URL structure.

### GET params

If you're using a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) like this `/api/general/reservation?enterprise=4&start=01-01-2015&end=01-31-2016`, your URI can be written in this form: `path[?query]`, path being `/api/general/reservation` and the query being `?enterprise=4&start=01-01-2015&end=01-31-2016`, which is optional and comes after the path.

To get those parameters you need to read their values from the request, e.g. `enterprise = request.GET['enterprise']`

So if you want to keep that structure, in your ViewSet, simply read those params your view methods

```
def do_something(request):
    # read the params first
    enterprise = request.GET['enterprise']
    ...
    # do something with those values
```

To use this scheme and match your *path* simply route like this

```
router.register(r'reservation', ReservationViewSet, 'reservation')
```

(There's no need to for the `r'reservation(?P<param>)'`, the query is not part of the path so do not include it)

### Parameters from URL matching

Otherwise, if you're trying to parse those directly from the URL e.g. with the URL regex, then you need a form more like this `/api/general/reservation/4/01-01-2015/01-31-2016` to be matched by something of this structure `reservation/(?P<enterprise>)/(?P<start>)/(?P<end>)`

And then your view method would look something like

```
def do_something(request, enterprise, start, end):
    # do something with those values
```

Comment: I am reading values from the request. Everything works till I have one parameter. I can't configure  router.py to resolve URL with 3 parameters.

Comment: If you want to go with the GET params, simply `router.register(r'reservation', ReservationViewSet)` is enough, no need to specify the parameters in the URL strucutre

Comment: bakkal, thank you much! this comment solved my problem. 
How should we go here as only your last comment solving my question?
(understand that my question was not clear)

Comment: bakkal,
thank you again for getting in to my question, you helped me much.